# VIM difference beetwen ] and . (Marks)

Tags: vim, editors

What is the difference between `]` and `.` in marks? I can't understand the difference. I noticed that if I enter insert mode (without inserting anything) and go out, the line in question appears in the register "**]**" ... why?

Answer (score 0):

You can read more on [Vim Tips Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks#Special_marks) but basically

> - **]** : jump to end of previously changed or yanked text
> - **.** : jump to position where last change occurred in current buffer

Comment: but I noticed that if I enter insert mode (without inserting anything) and go out, the line in question appears in the register "]" ... why?